# How to render handlebars template to HTML string in ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I would like to know how to translate

```
 var template = Handlebars.compile( $( '#row-tpl' ).html() );
```

within Ember.

I defined a template in products.js like this:

```
{{ProductName}}
```

That creates: Ember.TEMPLATES.products

But how do I render this to pure html ? I need the html to set the  content for a KendoUI window.

Regards
  Roger

Answer (score 5):

Use `{{{ProductName}}}` instead of `{{ProductName}}`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question/answer.  But in the event of someone landing here I just wanted to update the accepted answer

from having this in the template

`{{{safehtml}}`

instead return this from your computed property

`return Ember.String.htmlSafe(ProductName);`